# How to add another parameter in for the function in addlistenerevent in addition to the event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm using a JavaScript function as follows:-

```
function fileSelectHandler(e) {
    fileDragHover(e);
    // some more code
}

function init(){
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", fileSelectHandler, false);
}
```

Now I want to use another parameter in the listener function. I know I can add multiple parameters in the following way.

```
function init(){
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", function(){
        fileSelectHandler(a, b)
    }, false);
}
```

But how to pass the `e` in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
function init(){
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", function(e){
       fileSelectHandler(e,a,b);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Suren Srapyan is right,  and you can do like this :

```
function init(){
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", 
                                 callback,
                                ,false);
}

function callback() {
   fileSelectHandler(arguments[0],a,b)
}
```

Because of the second parameter of addEventListener is callback function, when 'change' event triggered, callback function will be called with parameter like :

```
callback(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()`

```
function fileSelectHandler(a, b, e) {
    fileDragHover(e, a, b);
    // some more code
}

fileselect.addEventListener("change"
, fileSelectHandler.bind(fileselect, a, b), false);
```